# Dynamic class constructor in c#

Tags: c#, oop, class, constructor

I have one class with 2 properties called MinValue, MaxValue , If somebody wants to invoke this class and Instantiate this class ,I need some to have constructor that allow select MinValue Or Max Value Or Both Of them , the MinValue and MaxValue both of them are int,
So the constructor doesn't allow me like this:

```
public class Constructor
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public Constructor(int MinValue, int MaxValue)
    {
        this.Min = MinValue;
        this.Max = MaxValue;
    }

    public Constructor(int MaxValue)
    {
        this.Max = MaxValue;
    }

    public Constructor(int MinValue)
    {
        this.Min = MinValue;
    }
}
```

Now I cannot do that because I cannot overload two constructor,
How Can I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create two *static* methods for the two parts where you've got only partial information. For example:

```
public Constructor(int minValue, int maxValue)
{  
    this.Min = minValue;
    this.Max = maxValue;
}

public static Constructor FromMinimumValue(int minValue)
{
    // Adjust default max value as you wish
    return new Constructor(minValue, int.MaxValue);
}

public static Constructor FromMaximumValue(int maxValue)
{
    // Adjust default min value as you wish
    return new Constructor(int.MinValue, maxValue);
}
```

(The C# 4 option of using named arguments is good too, but *only* if you know that all your callers will support named arguments.)

Comment: Yes. A good example of a type using this approach is `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: Why MinValue and MaxValue? Since `default(int)` is 0 I would expect that value when it is not provided.

Comment: The only problem is : with this solution code is not clear.because we can not hide the class constructor, Or we have one more constructor like setMinAndMaxValu beside our main constructor.

Comment: @n.podbielski: It seems odd to me for a min and max value to both be 0 by default. That would suggest that the only "minimum only" values you could sensibly provide would be negative. Basically we don't have enough information to say.

Comment: @PersianGolf: You could make the constructor private. It's not clear what your objection is, basically. (And calling code *is* clear...)

Answer (score 4):

You can't.
However, if you're using C# 4.0, you can do this:

```
class YourTypeName
{
    public YourTypeName(int MinValue = 1,  int MaxValue = 100)
    {  
        this.Min=MinValue;
        this.Max=MaxValue;
    }
}


var a = new YourTypeName(MinValue: 20);
var b = new YourTypeName(MaxValue: 80);
```

Or, in C# 3.0 and above, you can do this:

```
class YourTypeName
{
    public YourTypeName()
    {
    }

    public YourTypeName(int MinValue,  int MaxValue)
    {  
        this.Min=MinValue;
        this.Max=MaxValue;
    }

    public int Min {get;set;}

    public int Max {get;set;}
}

var a = new YourTypeName { Min = 20 };
var b = new YourTypeName { Max = 20 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Constructor(int minValue = 0, int maxValue = 0) // requires C# 4+
{
}
```

or

```
struct ValueInfo
{
    public MinValue { get; set; }
    public MaxValue { get; set; }
}

public Constructor(ValueInfo values) // one or another or both values can be specified
{
}
```